# Unable to display action bar with menu in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu

I have an app where I am displaying 4 fragments as tab bar. I also want an action bar with some menu items in the fragment view. I have added a menu xml file and done coding for it but it is not displaying. My code for fragment page:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.portfolio, menu);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.about,
            null);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Menu item:

```
<item
  android:id="@+id/add_item"
  android:icon="@drawable/plus"
  android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
  android:title="Add">
```

I have checked with debugger but it doesn't enter onCreateOptionsMenu method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ru using Sherlock library? If ur using then extending "SherlockFragment" class instead of "Fragment"

Comment: no I am not using any third party library